# Continuously get PHP loop data in Ajax Call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this codes in `process.php`:

```
$users = $_POST['users']; // Sample: "user1, user2, user5"
$users = explode(', ', $users);
$step = 0;
foreach ($users as $r) {
   $user_email = get_user_email($r); // Get email of each user
   if (!empty($user_email)) {
      send_w_mail(); // Send email to each user
      $step++;
      echo json_encode(
             ['step' => $step, 'all' => count($users)]
           ); // echo output
        }
    }
```

And this is my ajax call in `index.php`:

```
$("#send-message").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: global_base_url + 'process.php', // global_base_url defined.
        async : true,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'users': input_users}, // input_users is val() of a input.
        encoding: 'UTF-8',
        success: function (data) {
            data = $.trim(data);
            if (data){
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                var p_value = parseInt(data.step*100)/data.all;
                set_progressbar_value(p_value); // set progressbar value. sample: 23%
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This codes don't have any problem for execute and showing result.

But **I want to Continuously get output json data** from `process.php` in order to show process of each `$step` in Percent unit in a bootstrap process-bar;

I found some function like `ignore_user_abort()`, `ob_clean()` and `ob_flush()` but don't know how can I solve my problem with them.

How Can I do this? Please help me to solve the problem.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Spewing JSON endlessly is bound to be trouble. Can't you just poll on a 1-5 second update interval?

Comment: websockets or polling. Your method won't work for any extended period.

Comment: @tadman "Can't you just poll on a 1-5 second update interval?" How can I do this? Please provide a sample. Thanks.

Comment: @mkaatman Are you have other way/method to do this?

Comment: Yes, the two I mentioned in my first comment.

Comment: @mkaatman Thanks. Can you provide description and/or sample into an answer of this question?

Comment: They are not small features. Start by looking for tutorials on google

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of approaching this problem

1. Websocket
2. Long polling

I will be describing the long polling method here:

```
$users = $_POST['users']; // Sample: "user1, user2, user5"
$users = explode(', ', $users);
$step = 0;
foreach ($users as $r) {
    $user_email = get_user_email($r); // Get email of each user
    if (!empty($user_email)) {
        send_w_mail(); // Send email to each user
        $step++;
        echo json_encode(
            ['step' => $step, 'all' => count($users)]
        ); // echo output
        //Flush the output to browser
        flush();
        ob_flush();
    }
```

Jquery does not provide api for `XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 3` (Loading docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)) so we need to use raw `XMLHttpRequest` object

```
$("#send-message").click(function () {
    var prev_response = "";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", global_base_url + 'process.php', true);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(xhr.readyState == 3) {
            // Partial content loaded. remove the previous response   
            var partial_response = xhr.responseText.replace(prev_response,"");
            prev_response = xhr.responseText;
            //parse the data and do your stuff
            var data = $.parseJSON(partial_response);
            var p_value = parseInt(data.step*100)/data.all;        
            set_progressbar_value(p_value); 
        }
        else if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            set_progressbar_value(100);
            console.log("Completed");
        }

    }
    xhr.send("users="+ input_users); 

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Everything is normal like ajax when I using your code but partial_response or data is empty when processing. I added `console.log('responseText:' + xhr.responseText);` before `$.parseJSON` and I opened `index.php`. After ajax call started, When processing I can't see any log in console but I can see returned loop result when Ajax call finished. Is this solvable?

Comment: @Ayrese which server are you using ? May be some config problem with your server. [here](https://pastebin.com/cM6S5Akd) is a pastebin, copy paste it on [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite) and try it

Comment: @tinker can you send resources/demos/style.css file?